# MYSQL - Join three tables (in a row?)

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with coming up with the query required to do what I am after.

I have three tables like this:

```
client_files

-----------------------
client_id       file_id
-----------------------
1               2
1               3
1               6
2               1
2               2
3               5



files

-------------------------------------------------
ID           file_name           file_category_id
-------------------------------------------------
1            file1.ext           1
2            file2.ext           3
3            file3.ext           1
4            file4.ext           1
5            file5.ext           2
6            file6.ext           2



file_categories

--------------------------
ID           category_name           
--------------------------
1            category1
2            category2
3            category3
```

I am attempting to build a query which will return the filename and category name for a particular client ID.

The result I am expecting is (from ID 1):

```
-----------------------------
file_name       category_name
-----------------------------
file2.ext       category3
file3.ext       category1
file6.ext       category2
```

As far as I understand it, I need to join the `client_files` table to the `files` table and then to the `file_categories` table. I've looked at other examples which are about joining two tables with a 3rd table linking them together, but believe this is a different situation.

This is the equivalent of what I have come up with, but the results are almost random, with some files returned that are not linked, and some are missing.

```
    SELECT
  f.file_name,
  fc.category_name
FROM
  client_files cf,
  files f,
  file_categories fc
WHERE
  cf.client_id = 1 AND f.ID = cf.file_id AND fc.ID = f.file_category_id;
```

Comment: Please see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) on joining tables.

Comment: @JonStirling I'm reading as much as I can but I can't get my head around joining three in the way I am trying to do it. I don't understand why I am getting seemingly random results with this.

Comment: Your query returns the correct results for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc3bc9/1

Comment: You should get up to date and use ANSI JOIN syntax, but your query is still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have proper join conditions, right now you are doing cross join and then having the where condition.

```
SELECT
  cf.client_id,
  f.file_name,
  fc.category_name
FROM
  client_files cf
LEFT JOIN
  files f ON cf.file_id = f.ID
LEFT JOIN
  file_categories fc ON fc.ID = f.file_category_id
WHERE
  cf.client_id = 1;
```

Comment: A cross join with where conditions is functionally identical to inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways, but i thing essentially it's the same.

The first way:

```
SELECT
  f.file_name,
  fc.category_name
FROM
  client_files cf 
  JOIN files f ON cf.file_id = f.id
  JOIN file_categories fc ON fc.id = f.file_category_id
```

Or, the second way:

```
SELECT
  f.file_name,
  fc.category_name
FROM
  (client_files cf 
  JOIN files f ON cf.file_id = f.id) data1
  JOIN file_categories fc ON fc.id = data1.file_category_id
```

Comment: This is equivalent to his code. It just uses ANSI JOIN syntax instead of implicit joins.

Comment: You're missing `cf.client_id = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT files.file_name, file_categories.category_name 

FROM ((files LEFT JOIN client_files ON files.ID = client_files.file_id)

 LEFT JOIN file_categories ON files.file_category_id = file_categories.ID)

 WHERE client_files.client_id = 1
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` for this. You don't need rows that have no match.